# Explain why adding another point to the set of given points won't change the interpolating polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Find the interpolating polynomial for the given points $$(-1,3)\;\;(0,1)\;\;(1,1)\;\;(2,3)$$

Then add the point $(-2,7)$ to the set of your points and explain the result.

---

The unique interpolating polynomial of the function is given by $$L\left(x\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{3}y_{i}l_{i}\left(x\right)$$

Where $$l_{i}\left(x\right)=\prod_{m=0 \\ m \ne i }^{3 }\frac{x-x_{m}}{x_{i}-x_{m}}$$

So $$L\left(x\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{3}y_{i}l_{i}\left(x\right)=x^2-x+1$$

I also added the point $(-2,7)$ and noticed that the interpolating polynomial is the same as the above, by the properties of $L(x)$, I know that $L(x)-f(x)$ has at least $4$ roots, however I don't know if $L(x)-f(x)$ is of degree at most $3$ ,so this is why I cannot say $L(x)=f(x)$ and conclude that adding more points will not change the interpolating polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

In general, adding more points will change the polynomial. What happened in this case in that the new point is already in the graphic of the initial interpolating polynomial... If you start with a polynomial $p(x)$ and keep adding points of the form $(x_i, p(x_i))$, you will keep getting the same polynomial, and this is due to the uniqueness of the interpolating polynomial.

Comment: @masaheb Yes... What I'm saying is that, in general, the polynomial keeps changing as you add more points, but in this case the point that was added was redundant and the polynomial did not change. You should also keep in mind that is not always true that the graphic of the interpolating polynomial fits the graphics of $f$ as the number of points increase (search for Runge's example).